# How to add external dependecies while creating Visual Studio 2022 C++ DLL?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write dll which will be loaded by one software using LoadLibrary() function now i have external headers file included in DLL like Json.hpp and curl.h and dll getting build easily in X86 Release and Debug  mode also code working fine without errors in console app, But My software is unable to parse my .dll with LoadLibrary() function whenever i include libcurl and json.hpp code and make it do something it get's build but loadlibrary unable to parse my dll and header files are not getting linked the same headers files are getting linked easily in console app.

Comment: What do you mean by _"...My software is unable to parse my .dll with LoadLibrary() ..."_ what errors do you get ? `LoadLibrary` just tries to load the library there is no _"...parsing..."_ you do that later with `GetProcAddress`.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: Just for the records: _Header files_ are not _linked_. They are consumed by the compiler with the source files where they are included (by `#include`). The header files may contain declarations for which you have to add objects or libraries which the linker can resolve. Header files may as well contain definitions (so-called header-only libraries) where nothing extra needs to be linked.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat: True, but if the linker would fail with missing definitions, there wouldn't be a DLL that could be used with a console test app. We need more debugging details to be certain what the problem is, but we can already exclude some possibilities.

Comment: @MSalters Sorry. Maybe, I over-reacted to _header files are not getting linked_... ;-)